# Is there an indication in the cockpit when the refueling control panel door is open on the ATR72?

Tags: fuel-systems, atr-72

Is there any indication (light, MFD/SD displays) in the cockpit of opened/closed refueling control panel door in ATR72-600?

Comment: From [these notes](https://www.fosterweb.com/atr-notes/atrnotes.pdf) valid for ATR42 and 72: "*No warning if a fuel door, ground air conditioning access door, emergency exit, etc. is open.  Must check refueling panel door before flight if it was not closed during preflight or if it was opened after the preflight was completed.*"